# Laravel single line command for roll back and migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent

after rollback php artisan migrate:rollback --step 2 then I need to run command php artisan migrate . is there are any single command line for rollback and migrate ? like php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: php artisan migrate:refresh you can try refresh it drops table and again migrate

Comment: is there any method available without dropping table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may roll back & re-migrate a limited number of migrations by providing the step option to the refresh command. For example, the following command will roll back & re-migrate the last five migrations:

> php artisan migrate:refresh --step=2

Comment: The `& re-migrate the last five migrations` is wrong. It migrated 5 for you because that was the total migrations you had in your latest 2 batches, but it will vary. Please remove the `five` part of your answer, so you don't mislead future readers.
As a side note, I wonder why you care so much about SO reputation that you ask people to mark your answer as correct as part of the answer. If I were you, I'd stop caring that much. Saying that because I believe it's better for your mental health, and less frustrating for the readers. Win-win ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command

`php artisan migrate:rollback --step=2`

Also you can refer this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations